# Images not showing with next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js13

I had tried a lot to fix this issue that i am facing with images using Next.js, it not detect the image and showing [broken image icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7csRx.png) [here is my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMoDO.jpg) any solution for this issue?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to import it like a component like below

```
import Image from "next/image";
import logo from '../../../public/home/webImage/Be-logo.png';

<Image src={logo} alt="logo img"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).